# Mysterious ArgumentOutOfRangeException of datagridview with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, exception

This is my code:

```
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string command = "SELECT id, date, time, customer, employee, product, number_plate, tare, coef_tare, brutto, coef_brutto, net FROM base WHERE date BETWEEN '"+ theDate1+"' AND '"+theDate2+"';";
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command, conn);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(DS);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
            conn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex), "Exception. table sql", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

And I get ArgumentOutOfRangeException at this row:                 dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];

I don't know whats wrong here. This issue actually appeared when I added this to MySQL query
 ...WHERE date BETWEEN '"+ theDate1+"' AND '"+theDate2+"';";

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Maybe your select command query doesn't return any rows, causing the tables collection to stay empty (hence there is no Tables[0] and Tables.Count == 0). Beyond that your select query should use CommandParameters instead of string concat.

Comment: I see, but tab isnot empty. May be its becouse of time delay? Code works OK in 3 of 10 times I launc this whole method.

Comment: Why don't you add `Debug.WriteLine(theDate1);` to the catch  (do the same for theDate2) to see in the debugger for which combinations of parameters it will fail. Then check if those data parameters when inserted into that select statement return any rows.